# How to turn off recording for an EasyMock object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I am testing a servlet's `doPost()` method using EasyMock objects for the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` arguments.  Within the `doPost()` method I'm testing the request and response objects are used as arguments to a static method class for another class, and I want to disregard (i.e. not record as expected) any calls made on the request and response objects within this method call (it's not relevant to this test anyway). For example the `doPost()` method of the servlet class I'm testing looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                      final HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // handle an "updateFolder" event
    String eventParameter = servletRequest.getParameter("event");
    if ("updateFolder".equalsIgnoreCase(eventParameter))
    {
        // update the news documents folder settings
        String folderId = servletRequest.getParameter("folderId");
        IPortletContext portletContext = PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        IPortletResponse portletResponse = portletContext.getResponse();
        portletResponse.setSettingValue(SettingType.CommunityPortlet, "NEWS_DOCUMENTS_FOLDER_ID", folderId);
    }

    // redirect to the appropriate URL
    servletResponse.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

When the above code gets to the step where `PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext()` is called I don't really care what method calls are made on the request and response objects within that method, but if I pass in mock request and response objects when testing this method I get errors from EasyMock telling me that there are missing behavior definitions.  For example I have a test method which looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testPostWithUpdate()
    throws Exception
{
    // create mock objects and record their expected calls
    HttpServletRequest mockServletRequest = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse mockServletResponse = createMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    IPortletResponse mockPortletResponse = createMock(IPortletResponse.class);
    IPortletContext mockPortletContext = createMock(IPortletContext.class);
    expect(mockServletRequest.getContextPath()).andReturn(null);
    expect(mockServletRequest.getParameter("event")).andReturn("updateFolder");
    expect(mockServletRequest.getParameter("folderId")).andReturn(null);
    expect(PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext(mockServletRequest, mockServletResponse)).andReturn(mockPortletContext);
    expect(mockPortletContext.getResponse()).andReturn(mockPortletResponse);
    mockPortletResponse.setSettingValue(SettingType.CommunityPortlet, "NEWS_DOCUMENTS_FOLDER_ID", null);
    mockServletResponse.sendRedirect(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class));

    // take the mock objects out of record state
    replay(mockPortletContext, mockPortletResponse, mockServletRequest, mockServletResponse);

    // instantiate an object of the class and run the method we want to test
    ControllerServlet controllerServlet = new ControllerServlet();
    controllerServlet.doPost(mockServletRequest, mockServletResponse);

    // verify that our mocks behaved as expected
    verify(mockPortletContext, mockPortletResponse, mockServletRequest, mockServletResponse);
}
```

I get the following error when I run the test class:

```
com.plumtree.openfoundation.util.XPIllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getCharacterEncoding()
    at com.plumtree.openfoundation.util.XPException.GetInstance(XPException.java:397)
    at com.plumtree.openfoundation.util.XPException.GetInstance(XPException.java:350)
    at com.plumtree.openfoundation.web.XPRequest.InitRequest(XPRequest.java:201)
    at com.plumtree.openfoundation.web.XPRequest.<init>(XPRequest.java:111)
    at com.plumtree.remote.portlet.PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext(PortletContextFactory.java:32)
    at com.abc.servlet.ControllerServletTest.testPostWithUpdate(ControllerServletTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getCharacterEncoding()
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:43)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:73)
    at $Proxy4.setCharacterEncoding(Unknown Source)
    at com.plumtree.openfoundation.web.XPRequest.InitRequest(XPRequest.java:135)
    ... 25 more
```

I assume that the errors above are caused by not recording the method calls executed within the `PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext()` method on the mock request and response objects passed in as arguments.  If this is actually what's happening here then how can I rework things so that the method calls made on the request and response mocks by the `PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext()` method are disregarded?

Answer (score 2):

Try Mockito http://mockito.org/.

It is much easier to use from EasyMock, and doesn't force you to code all the method calls.

Comment: Neither does EasyMock - it has _nice mocks_ for that. And ease of use is to a large extent a question of personal taste and experience.

Comment: @Peter I worked with both and now I prefer Mockito. This may be a matter of taste, still IMHO Mockito has a neater API. TO put it in other words, Mockito is a nice mock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need something like this:

```
expect(mockServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()).andReturn("UTF-8");
```

Or use createNiceMock() as Péter Török suggests.

Comment: You may encounter other methods not implemented by your mock, so createNiceMock() may work unless null causes other errors.

Comment: Yes, the above is what I'm trying to avoid, since I'm not sure what method calls are being made on the mock request within the third party class method, and it's not relevant anyway since I'm not testing that class.  If the third party class implementation changes then my test may break using the approach described above.  For example it looks like PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext() is calling getCharacterEncoding() on the mock request, and if the implementation of that method changes then my test will fail if I have that expectation on the mock object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext` call. EasyMock itself does not support static method mocking, however PowerMock extension for EasyMock does. Here is the sample code you should insert into your test:

```
mockStatic(PortletContextFactory.class);     
expect(PortletContextFactory.createPortletContext(mockServletRequest, mockServletResponse)).andReturn(mockPortletContext);
replay(PortletContextFactory.class);
```

There are also 2 requirements:

1. Use the
   `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
   annotation at the class-level of the
   test case.
2. Use the `@PrepareForTest(PortletContextFactory.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case.

Read more at: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Comment: Yes, PowerMock let you do this, but this approach should only be used with legacy code and having to use Powermock to test classes at design time is certainly a sign of bad design.

Comment: @Pierre-Henri Yes, usage and mocking of static methods should be avoided by all means. However _OP_ didn't explicitly mention in his question whether he's testing legacy code or designing a new one (or at least have permission to modify it).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach to test in similar scenarios :

```
class Class_Under_Test {
  public void A() {
    B b = C.create(); //create is static
    D d = e.(b);
  }
}
```

To get around the static reference problem in EasyMock you can change your method definition to :

```
@VisibleForTesting
B create() {
  return C.create();
}

public A() {
  B b = create();
  D d = e.(b); 
}
```

In your test class you can do this :

```
Class testSomething {

  private Mock_Class_Under_Test mockOject;//Class Defined below 
  private B mockB;

  @Override
  void setup() {
    mockB  =createMock(B.class);
  }  

  private class Mock_Class_Under_Test extends Class_Under_Test {

      @Override
      B create() {
        return mockB;
      }
  }

  public void testA() {
    //No need to put expectation on static call as create() will always return mock.
    expect(e.something(mockB)).andReturn(somethingElse);   
  }
}
```

All your further tests will use mockObject to call methods of the Class_Under_Test.

Answer (score 1):

To turn of the recording, use a nice mock. From the documentation :

> On a Mock Object returned by `createMock()` the default behavior for all
>   methods is to throw an `AssertionError` for all unexpected method calls.
>   If you would like a "nice" Mock Object that by default allows all
>   method calls and returns appropriate empty values (0, null or false),
>   use `createNiceMock()` instead.

Also, more generally, what you want to mock is `createPortletContext(servletRequest, servletResponse)`. Unfortunately that's a static call.
To achieve this mock, create you own factory that will return the `portletContext`, and pass this factory to you tested class (preferably in the constructor). 
Mock this factory and the `portletContext` too, so you can test only what matter here : the code you wrote.

Comment: A separate factory for `portletContext` is a good approach. However @OP will not be able to pass it to the constructor since he's testing a servlet (which requires public no-args constructor). But it's possible to create a setter in the servlet and call it in the test-case to pass a mocked version of the factory (obviously the default factory implementation must be set in the servlet default constructor)

Comment: The best approach for this problem is in my opinion to delegate the doPost call to a plan java service you can have total control over.
This might be overkill, so @Idolon approach to use a setter is perfectly valid too.